# How to make SQL comparisons by using values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, case, query-optimization

I have below table like this :

**Table-1 :**

[image]

I want to make few segments (ScoreType) in Table-1 by using below ranges from Table-2.

**Table-2:**

[image]

I have used simple case statement and used values from table-2 for comparison as I can update that table any time instead of manual changes in the query.

**Code for making tables :**

```
--Table 1
Create table BandRange(
    [ScoreType] Varchar(10)
    ,[MinDemand] INT
    ,[MaxDemand] INT
    ,[MinFrequency] INT
    ,[MaxFrequency] INT
    ,[ForWhat] Varchar(10) 
);

Insert into BandRange
values
 ('ND-NF' , 0,0,0,0,'QtrYear')
,('ND-LF' , 0,0,0,5,'QtrYear')
,('ND-MF' , 0,0,6,15,'QtrYear')
,('ND-HF' , 0,0,16,99999,'QtrYear')

,('LD-NF' , 1,2,0,0,'QtrYear')
,('LD-LF' , 1,2,0,5,'QtrYear')
,('LD-MF' , 1,2,6,15,'QtrYear')
,('LD-HF' , 1,2,16,99999,'QtrYear')

,('MD-NF' , 3,5,0,0,'QtrYear')
,('MD-LF' , 3,5,0,5,'QtrYear')
,('MD-MF' , 3,5,6,15,'QtrYear')
,('MD-HF' , 3,5,16,99999,'QtrYear')

,('HD-NF' , 6,99999,0,0,'QtrYear')
,('HD-LF' , 6,99999,0,5,'QtrYear')
,('HD-MF' , 6,99999,6,15,'QtrYear')
,('HD-HF' , 6,99999,16,99999,'QtrYear');

--Table 2
create table QtrScores(MUID INT NOT NULL,Demand INT NOT NULL,Frequency INT NOT NULL);
Insert into QtrScores Values
(1,52,35),
(2,0,5),
(3,5,2),
(4,1,81),
(5,6,5),
(6,4,0),
(7,14,1)
```

**My code :**

```
--select * from QtrScores
--select * from BandRange

select MUID,Frequency,Demand,
    case 
        --1st
        when (Demand = (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-NF') 
            or Demand = ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-NF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency = (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-NF')  
            or  Frequency = (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-NF') 
             ) 
            then 'ND-NF' 
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-LF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-LF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency >= (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-LF')  
            and Frequency <= (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-LF') 
             ) 
            then 'ND-LF' 
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-MF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-MF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency >= (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-MF')  
            and  Frequency <= (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-MF') 
             ) 
            then 'ND-MF' 
        when (Demand <= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-HF') 
            and Demand >= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-HF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency >= (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-HF')  
            and Frequency <= (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='ND-HF') 
             ) 
            then 'ND-HF' 
        
        --2nd
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-NF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-NF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency = (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-NF')  
            and Frequency = (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-NF') 
             ) 
            then 'LD-NF' 
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-LF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-LF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency >= (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-LF')  
            and  Frequency <= (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-LF') 
             ) 
            then 'LD-LF' 
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-MF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-MF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency >= (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-MF')  
            and  Frequency <= (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-MF') 
             ) 
            then 'LD-MF' 
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-HF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-HF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency >= (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-HF')  
            and  Frequency <= (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='LD-HF') 
             ) 
            then 'LD-HF'

        --3rd
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-NF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-NF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency = (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-NF')  
            and  Frequency = (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-NF') 
             ) 
            then 'MD-NF' 
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-LF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-LF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency >= (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-LF')  
            and  Frequency <= (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-LF') 
             ) 
            then 'MD-LF' 
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-MF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-MF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency >= (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-MF')  
            and  Frequency <= (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-MF') 
             ) 
            then 'MD-MF' 
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-HF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-HF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency >= (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-HF')  
            and Frequency <= (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='MD-HF') 
             ) 
            then 'MD-HF'
        
        --4th
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-NF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-NF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency = (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-NF')  
            and  Frequency = (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-NF') 
             ) 
            then 'HD-NF' 
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-LF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-LF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency >= (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-LF')  
            and  Frequency <= (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-LF') 
             ) 
            then 'HD-LF' 
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-MF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-MF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency >= (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-MF')  
            and  Frequency <= (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-MF') 
             ) 
            then 'HD-MF' 
        when (Demand >= (select MinDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-HF') 
            and Demand <= ( select MaxDemand from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-HF' ) 
            ) and ( 
            Frequency >= (select MinFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-HF')  
            and  Frequency <= (select MaxFrequency from  BandRange(nolock) where ForWhat = 'QtrYear' and ScoreType ='HD-HF') 
             ) 
            then 'HD-HF'
            else 'NA'
        End  as ScoreType
    from QtrScores(nolock)
```

I have around 25M records in table-1 for QtrYear which is taking around 1 hr 30 mins to execute. I have mutiple conditions for various QtrYear, HalfYear,Yearwise which took 10+ hours to execute. Is there a better way of doing this?

*Link for SQL Fiddle:* http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60c62/5

Comment: Getting rid of all those subqueries would be a massive move towards fixing the performance. Getting rid of the `NOLOCK` hint is another, as for such a long running query I don't doubt you'll end up with incorrect results (you know `NOLOCK does that, right?). Note, as well, these are `CASE` **expressions**, not statements. T-SQL doesn't supprt `Case` (`Switch`) statements, which change the logical flow of an operation, only `CASE` expressions.

Comment: You may want to consider including the desired output for your sample data.

Comment: What results do you want?  The question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

The most logical interpretation of what you want to do is simply a `join`:

```
select *
from QtrScores q join
     BandRange b
     on q.demand between b.mindemand and b.maxdemand and
        q.frequency between b.minfrequency and b.maxfrequency;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60c62/6) is a SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

The challenge here is you are making 25 million records times 4 queries against the BandRange table - 50 million select queries - would be enough for even the largest servers to choke -

Think about this differently - Let the data work for you - prepare an index for the relevant banding as you load the QtrScores Table -

Added benefit - If you ever need to add new conditions in the future - you'll want to not need to maintain the case statement. Simply adding or changing the BandRanges record set will be easy, and updating the QtrScores will be an overnight loading process that won't need changes-  Note the BandRange_ID is synthetic and not to be used for reference.

**Step 1 - apply a numeric identity key on the BandRange Table**

**Step1a - Deploy a Tally Table**

**Step 1b - bind a numeric key onto the BandRanges -**

**Step 2 - prepare to maintain a new column on the QtrScores Table**

**Step 2a - deploy a scalar function that will keep QtrScores new column up to date**

**Step 2b - Add an Integer Column to the QtrScores - and NonClustered Index for good measure**

**Step 3 - update the new column on the QtrScores table using the function above (regularly)**

**Step 4 - The final ouput with a new simple query**

*Now For the Details*

**Step 1 - apply a numeric identity key on the BandRange Table -**
Personally - if you don't want to change the BandRange Table - use a new table called tally
**** Step 1a - Deploy Tally Table ****
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1

```
--=============================================================================
--      Setup Tally Table
--=============================================================================
    USE TempDB     --DB that everyone has where we can cause no harm
    SET NOCOUNT ON --Supress the auto-display of rowcounts for appearance/speed
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME    --Timer to measure total duration
    SET @StartTime = GETDATE() --Start the timer
--=============================================================================
--      Create and populate a Tally table
--=============================================================================
--===== Conditionally drop and create the table/Primary Key
     IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Tally') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE dbo.Tally
 CREATE TABLE dbo.Tally 
        (N INT, 
         CONSTRAINT PK_Tally_N PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (N))
--===== Create and preset a loop counter
DECLARE @Counter INT
    SET @Counter = 1
--===== Populate the table using the loop and couner
  WHILE @Counter <= 11000
  BEGIN
         INSERT INTO dbo.Tally
                (N)
         VALUES (@Counter)
            SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
    END
--===== Display the total duration
 SELECT STR(DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,GETDATE())) + ' Milliseconds duration'
```

****Step 1b - bind a numeric key onto the BandRanges -****
using the tally table (there is probably a cleaner router than "Top" - but here for expediency

```
create function [dbo].[fntab_BandRange_Indexed] () returns table return
-- select * from [dbo].[fntab_BandRange_Indexed] () 
select Top (select brrows = count(1) from BandRange) 
[BandRange_ID] = cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.N) as integer)
, BandRange.* from BandRange
cross apply tempdb.dbo.tally t
GO
```

Test with this query (adjust where and and)

```
select BandRange_ID = min([BandRange_ID])
from fntab_BandRange_Indexed ()
where 0 between MinDemand and MaxDemand 
and 0 Between MinFrequency and MaxFrequency
```

**Step 2 - prepare to maintain a new column on the QtrScores Table**

**Step 2a - deploy a scalar function**
to be used in a regular update the of QtrScores Table (new column yet to be created)

```
create function sclr_BandRange_Indexed_Sel ( @Demand integer, @Frequency integer) 
returns integer as
begin
declare @bandrange_id integer
select @BandRange_ID = cast(min([BandRange_ID]) as integer)
from fntab_BandRange_Indexed ()
where @Demand between MinDemand and MaxDemand 
and @Frequency Between MinFrequency and MaxFrequency
return @BandRange_ID 
end
```

**Step 2b - Add a Integer Column to the QtrScores - and NonClustered Index for good measure**
(will essentially become a [unenforced] FK to the fntab_BandRange_Indexed.BandRange_ID column

```
alter table QtrScores add [BandRange_ID] integer;
create nonclustered index idx_QtrScores_BandRangeID_MUID_Demand_Frequency on QtrScores (BandRange_ID, MUID, Demand, Frequency);
```

**Step 3 - update the new column on the QtrScores table using the function above (regularly)**
Apply the update on the BandRange_ID in your schedule each time you append the QtrScores Table (Could use a trigger on insert - but this is to illustrate)

```
update QtrScores  
   set [BandRange_ID] = dbo.sclr_BandRange_Indexed_Sel ( Demand, Frequency )
```

**Step 4 - The final ouput with a new simple query**
Instead of the giant and clunky case statement - you can now recreate your expected result
with a simple inner join

```
select QtrScores.MUID, QtrScores.Frequency, QtrScores.Demand, brind.ScoreType
from QtrScores
inner join [fntab_BandRange_Indexed]() brind on brind.BandRange_ID = QtrScores.BandRange_ID
 -- where [ForWhat] in ('QtrYear')
order by MUID
```

Note - as the "ForWhat" is a constant in the case statement I have not added it in - but it is easy to do with the final SQL Statement (Step 4)